# How to merge two rows related to the same transaction but with different pieces of information in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table containing transactions with two different types of transactions (transfers & orders), the buyer_id is only stored with a transfer event however the price is stored on the order event. How do I merge these two rows so that I have a single row with the buyer_id and price on the same line?

Here's what the table looks like:

```
Order ID   Trans ID    Timestamp            Category ID   Buyer ID   Price   Event type
4646820767  347571948  2022-04-02 10:05:48   8699308                 75      order
4646820796  347571948  2022-04-02 10:05:48   8699308      2530070            transfer
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```sql
select a.order_id, a.asset_id, a.timestamp, a.category_id, b.buyer_id, a.price
from table a 
inner join table b
  on a.trans_id = b.trans_id
```

Comment: Which `Order ID` should this new lines have?

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not wrong; but mot complete; It needs two additional condition.

```
select a.order_id, a.asset_id, a.timestamp, a.category_id, b.buyer_id, a.price
from table a 
inner join table b
  on a.trans_id = b.trans_id and a.Buyer_id is not null and a.price is not null
```

Comment: Maybe change `and a.price is not null` to `and b.price is not null` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lead()` and `lag()` to fill the missing info in every line instead of using an `inner join` of the entire table.

```
select  Order_ID
       ,Trans_ID
       ,time 
       ,Category_ID 
       ,case when Buyer_ID is null then lead(Buyer_ID) over(partition by trans_id order by order_id) else Buyer_ID end as Buyer_ID
       ,case when price is null then lag(price) over(partition by trans_id order by order_id) else price end           as price
      ,Event_type

from    t
```

| order_id | trans_id | time | category_id | buyer_id | price | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4646820767 | 347571948 | 2022-04-02 10:05:48 | 8699308 | 2530070 | 75 | order |
| 4646820796 | 347571948 | 2022-04-02 10:05:48 | 8699308 | 2530070 | 75 | transfer |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lZNsVkh6)